# how to use $scope in angularjs service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am storing my api response in a `$scope` variable. I have written in my main controller. Instead of that i am planning to write in one service file and need to use it in all controller. Right now i am re-writing the code in all controller. So that my application is getting slow.

**MainController.js :**

```js
$scope.UserId = reply.split('UserId=').pop().toUpperCase();
apiService.getResponseData($scope.UserId).then(function(reply) {
  $scope.responseData = reply.data;
  $timeout(function() {
    reply.data.forEach(function(card) {
      if (card.Category == 'Apple') {
        console.log("Apple");
      } else if (card.Category == 'Google') {
        console.log("Google");
      } else if (card.Category == 'Microsoft') {
        console.log("Microsoft");
      } else if (card.Category == 'Amazon') {
        console.log("Amazon");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

This is my mainController. How can I use this same code in my service.js file.

**CommonService.js :**

```js
app.service('commonService', ['$timeout', '$rootScope', 'apiService',
  function($timeout, $rootScope, apiService) {
    this.app = function($scope) {
      $scope.UserId = reply.split('UserId=').pop().toUpperCase();
      apiService.getResponseData($scope.UserId).then(function(reply) {
        $scope.responseData = reply.data;
        $timeout(function() {
          reply.data.forEach(function(card) {
            if (card.Category == 'Apple') {
              console.log("Apple");
            } else if (card.Category == 'Google') {
              console.log("Google");
            } else if (card.Category == 'Microsoft') {
              console.log("Microsoft");
            } else if (card.Category == 'Amazon') {
              console.log("Amazon");
            }

          });
        });
      });
      return app;
    };
  }
]);
```

`$scope` will not work in service file. Instead of this how can i use in other way. Can anyone please modify the above code. I want to use this code from service to multiple controllers..

Comment: Use `return reply.data;`. Not only will it solve the immediate problem, but the more you return results from functions instead of mutating state, the better your code will be.

Comment: can you please modify the code?

Answer (score 0):

Can be used but not a good case

**MainController.js :**

```
commonService.something($scope);
```

**CommonService.js:**

```
app.service('commonService', ['$timeout', '$rootScope', 'apiService',
    function ($timeout, $rootScope, apiService) {
        var something = function (scope) {
            apiService.getResponseData(scope.UserId).then(function (reply) {
                scope.responseData = reply.data;
                $timeout(function () {
                    reply.data.forEach(function (card) {
                        if (card.Category == 'Apple') {
                            console.log("Apple");
                        } else if (card.Category == 'Google') {
                            console.log("Google");
                        } else if (card.Category == 'Microsoft') {
                            console.log("Microsoft");
                        } else if (card.Category == 'Amazon') {
                            console.log("Amazon");
                        }

                    });
                });
            });
        };

        return {
            'something': something
        }
    }
]);
```