# how to use same if conditions in multiple controllers in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to use the if condition in multiple controllers. Instead of writing again and again how can I do in a simple way.

**MainController.js :**

```js
 $scope.responseData.forEach(function(card) {

    if (card.Category == 'Apple') {
         console.log("Apple");
       } else if (card.Category == 'Google') {
         console.log("Google");
       } else if (card.Category == 'Microsoft') {
         console.log("Microsoft");
       } else if (card.Category == 'Amazon') {
         console.log("Amazon");
    }
});
```

**FirstController.js :**

```js
$scope.responseData.forEach(function(card) {
    if (card.Category == 'Apple') {
         console.log("Apple");
       } else if (card.Category == 'Google') {
         console.log("Google");
       } else if (card.Category == 'Microsoft') {
         console.log("Microsoft");
       } else if (card.Category == 'Amazon') {
         console.log("Amazon");
    }
});
```

**SecondController.js :**

```js
$scope.responseData.forEach(function(card) {

    if (card.Category == 'Apple') {
         console.log("Apple");
       } else if (card.Category == 'Google') {
         console.log("Google");
       } else if (card.Category == 'Microsoft') {
         console.log("Microsoft");
       } else if (card.Category == 'Amazon') {
         console.log("Amazon");
    }

});
```

Like this how can I use this condition in one place and use it in many controllers.

Comment: Create a function which takes `card` or `Category` as an argument and reuse it

Comment: Please see my modified code what i am using exactly

Comment: Which modified code?

Comment: Please look at the code I'm using this code right now.

Comment: @adiga please look this link. Nobody is answering for this question. Please check and let me know.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62190058/how-to-use-scope-in-angularjs-service

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your question correctly one way that you can do this is using factory. 
I wrote an example here : https://jsbin.com/veregejawo/1/edit?html,js,console,output
I hope this help you:
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app">

<div ng-controller="mainController">
  {{controller}}
  <br>
  <button ng-click="testfactory('Apple')">Apple</button>
</div>

<div ng-controller="firstController">
  {{controller}}
  <br>
  <button ng-click="testfactory('Google')">Google</button>
</div>

<div ng-controller="secondController">
  {{controller}}
  <br>
  <button ng-click="testfactory('Microsoft')">Microsoft</button>
</div>

<script>

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('app', []);
angular.module('app').factory('ifFactory', function () {

    var factory = {};
    factory.checkIf = function (param) {
        if (param == 'Apple') {
           console.log("Apple");
         } else if (param == 'Google') {
           console.log("Google");
         } else if (param == 'Microsoft') {
           console.log("Microsoft");
         } else if (param == 'Amazon') {
           console.log("Amazon");
         }
    };
    return factory;

});

angular.module('app').controller('mainController', ['$scope', 'ifFactory',
    function ($scope, ifFactory) {
      $scope.controller = "mainController";

      $scope.testfactory = function(param){
        ifFactory.checkIf(param);
      }
    }
]);

angular.module('app').controller('firstController', ['$scope', 'ifFactory',
    function ($scope, ifFactory) {
      $scope.controller = "FirstController";

      $scope.testfactory = function(param){
        ifFactory.checkIf(param);
      }
    }
]);

angular.module('app').controller('secondController', ['$scope', 'ifFactory',
    function ($scope, ifFactory) {
      $scope.controller = "SecondController";

      $scope.testfactory = function(param){
        ifFactory.checkIf(param);
      }
    }
]);
```